# Open pdf in webview of android

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to open pdf in webview of android,

I tried using :

`webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+url)`

If url is `http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf`(this is a sample), its working fine,

but if url is `http://192.168.x.xxx:8001/ql/Demo/Demo_Rep_DDForm.pdf` its not opening.

Unable to figure out the reason, the above IP is public.

Comment: 192.168.x.xxx:8001/ ===> This is your internal network's IP Address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the above IP is public

No, it is not. IPs in the range you've provided are internal IP addresses used within a LAN network. Your public IP is something different, and you will have to find that out and use it to serve up your file using Google Docs.

You can get your public IP by simply typing `my public ip` into Google.

Additionally, public IPs change quite frequently (unless you're paying extra for a static IP to your ISP), so you would be better of hiring a server, or keeping your file in public domain somewhere to allow unbroken access to it.

Comment: @AnilM See my edit for details on how to get your current public IP.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this if it could help someone some day,

As an alternative , In order to view pdf files in android you can make use of the [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) which requires you to add the web related files in assets folder which includes the js files in the index.html and call the index.html by passing the url of the pdf file as query parameter and load it in the webview.

Pros:
User need not navigate away from the webview
You can reuse the same to display PDFs which are hosted in server or available withing the application also you can view pdf which require to login using cookies.

Cons:
There will be a slight increase in app size.

Comment: Sure, you can override the method `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`  and detect that a pdf is loaded, as below `if(url.contains(".pdf")) {
                    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file="+url);
                    return true;
                }` , this will load the url mentioned above in the webview and the library files which you have added in the assets folder as mentioned in my answer will help load the pdf in the webview. @statosdotcom

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To be honest, I didn't get pdf.js to work, all I get is a grey (blank) page. Sorry for the delay to return here.

Comment: @statosdotcom So have you got any alternative workaround or your would like to get suggestions on the fix? Best bet is that you might not have got all the support files included in your assets folder. Are you are able to see any logs at the least?

Comment: My friend, I appreciated very much your promptness and attention, thank you. Well, not a sign of error, but doesn't work at all. Maybe is my device or the version of API it runs. Searched a lot at the web and the complains about pdf.js are very popular. It would be very very nice if it worked here, but i ve spent lots of hours on this and can't have a single clue. Nothing abnormal at logcat. Each solution here at SO, with pdf.js, uses a different version of it, with files i dont have here... etc, well, is chaotic, a mess. Again: Thank you very much. Wish you all the best.